# How to plot multiple response survey items in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survey

I have survey data structured into several item variables that denote whether something was mentioned (`1`) or not mentioned (`2`) by a survey respondent. So in short, each row is for a different survey respondent and they can either choose all options a through c (as is the case for the third respondent in the data below), or none or just some.

Let this be the dataset:

```
testdat<-data.frame(option_a=c(1,2,2,1,2),
                    option_b=c(1,1,2,1,2),
                    option_c=c(1,1,2,1,1))
```

What would be the easiest and fastest way to plot just the relative frequencies of how often any option was chosen? The outcome should be a geom_bar plot with three bars representing the different options (a: 40%, b: 60%, c: 20%). Put differently, I would like to have a plot based on which I could say, a given option was chosen in x% of the cases by the respondents.

Is there a way by which I could do this directly in ggplot without having to restructure the dataset or replace `2`s by `0`s, etc.? I guess this should be fairly easy, but I just can't see it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a barplot you need to make your data into a long format. You cannot do that within the `ggplot` function itself. You can change the levels of the values within `ggplot`, nut you will also need to rename the `fill` legend.

```
testdat<-data.frame(option_a=c(1,2,2,1,2),
                    option_b=c(1,1,2,1,2),
                    option_c=c(1,1,2,1,1))

require(ggplot2)
require(tidyverse)

testdat %>%
  gather(option,value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(option), fill = factor((value-2)*-1))) +
  geom_bar()
```

to get the percentages/proportions instead of `n` you can summarise the data before plotting the data like so:

```
testdat %>%
  gather(option, value) %>%
  group_by(option,value) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(option) %>%
  mutate(percentage = n/sum(n)*100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(option), y = percentage, fill = factor((value-2)*-1))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

EDIT:

only show the relative frequencies of one of the options:

```
testdat %>%
  gather(option, value) %>%
  group_by(option,value) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(option) %>%
  mutate(percentage = n/sum(n)*100) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(option), y = percentage, fill = factor((value-2)*-1))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: There is no need to calculate the proportion outside of ggplot in this case. You can use `geom_bar(aes(y = stat(count/sum(count))), position = position_fill())` or `geom_bar(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)), position = position_fill())` (depending on your ggplots version)

Comment: OK thanks, I thought there might be away to do this directly in ggplot, but I'll need to restructure the data then. Do you know why I can't just specify `y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)` to get my relative frequencies? Even if I recode my measure variables into {1,0} binary variables, this doesn't work.

Comment: @kath: Thanks for that. But for some reason, *100 doesn't seem to work. I still get y values from 0-1 instead of 0% to 100%.

Comment: @FabianHabersack use `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)` for a nice formating of the y axis

Comment: Right, that works. And last question: how would I get rid of the stacked bar charts and just plot the relative frequencies of actual mentions of these options (that is, only `1`, and not `2`)?

Comment: So you want to filter or subset your data? Well than you should try `?subset` or `?filter`. Search for "How to filter my data in R" or related...

Comment: I'm not really sure I want to subset my data, because how would I do that? For instance if I say `filter(option_a==1)` I will be left with one row of data and that makes no sense. Likewise, I could just say that all `2`s should be `NA`s, but then I would still see the NA-stacks in my relative frequency plot. So, I'm not sure how to exclusively focus on the relative frequency of `1`s for plotting...

Comment: If you don't want the plot to be stacked, than you can use: `geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())` if you want to get rid of one of the two options than you would need to subset the data after you calculated the relative percentages. Can't do that within ggplot I think. see edit.